# Can I restrict or constrain an SQL table with Start and End dates, to only allow one "active" row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints, temporal-tables

PROBLEM: with a given SQL Server table, is it possible to 'constrain' or use a 'unique index' so it only allows users to enter rows where we have only one "Active/Live" row based on the start and end dates?

Example database schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Service]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ServiceName] varchar(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Service] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServiceRate]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ServiceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CountryId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ServiceRate] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ServiceRate] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ServiceRate_Service] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ServiceId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Service] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ServiceRate] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ServiceRate_Service]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ServiceRate] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_ServiceRate_StartDate_EndDate] 
        CHECK  (([StartDate] <= COALESCE([EndDate], '9999-12-31')))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ServiceRate] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_ServiceRate_StartDate_EndDate]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UX_ServiceId_EndDate_CountryId] 
ON [dbo].[ServiceRate] ([ServiceId] ASC, [EndDate] ASC, [CountryId] ASC)
```

So for example if I populate the `[ServiceRate]` table with data like this:

| ID | ServiceId | StartDate | EndDate | CountryId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 53 |
| 5 | 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 70 |
| 6 | 2 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 0 |
| 7 | 2 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL | 53 |
| 9 | 1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 0 <--- THIS SHOULD ERROR (conflict row 1) |
| 11 | 1 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 2023-02-27 00:00:00.000 | 0 <--- THIS SHOULD ERROR (conflict row 9) |

NOTE: `CountryId` of 0 means "all countries"

Then as long as the columns are unique for `([ServiceId], [CountryId])` but also have separate "live" date ranges from `[StartDate]` and `[EndDate]`, then everything is good.

But I want SQL Server to throw an error when trying to add row 9 as this conflicts with the same "Active/Live" date range as row 1 (as well as having a duplicate for `ServiceId` and `CountryId`)

Also if row 1 wasn't - there then this should also throw an error on row 11 as this conflicts with the same "Active/Live" date range as row 9 (as well as having a duplicate for `ServiceId` and `CountryId`).

So another way to explain this is to say - can I restrict data in the table, so that this query will never return a `[rec]` value greater than 1 when run for any date?

```sql
DECLARE @dt datetime = '2023-02-14'

SELECT ServiceId, CountryId, COUNT(*) rec
FROM [dbo].[ServiceRate]
WHERE @dt >= StartDate
  AND @dt <  COALESCE(EndDate, '9999-12-31')
GROUP BY ServiceId, CountryId
```

I've got so far with a `CONSTRAINT` and `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX` but I can't quite figure this out.

I've seen other articles that describe a query with a LAG function - but this only works if the preceding `[EndDate]` matches exactly the next `[StartDate]` for that `(ServiceId, CountryId)` group.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580056/sql-interview-prevent-overlapping-date-range

Comment: The tile says "Date" and the example data has no non zero time component but the datatype is `datetime`. Is it dates or date time?

Comment: I've reopened the question. You aren't using Oracle so I have no idea why that was selected as a duplicate. The self join in the accepted answer would not be possible in a SQL Server indexed view. Nor can check constraints be added to SQL Server indexed views

Comment: Potentially you could join onto a calendar table and expand the ranges out to dates and then put that into an indexed view with a unique index but if you are actually using arbitrary precision datetime rather than just dates the number of rows required in the calendar table may make this impossible

Comment: I would not put logic like this in the database, application should do a query before creating a ServiceRate on whether or not it should

Comment: @RaymondHolmboe - I totally agree. However, I think I am concerned that DBA, Managers or Bulk Insert of data could potential create "bad data with overlapping start and end dates". If I can prevent this at the database level - that would be a bonus :-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be a TRIGGER on table ServiceRate.

```
Create Trigger CheckDateData ON ServiceRate 
INSTEAD OF Insert
AS
IF EXISTS (
Select Top 1 A.StartDate, A.EndDate, B.StartDate, B.EndDate 
  from ServiceRate A
  INNER JOIN Inserted B ON B.ServiceID = A.ServiceId AND B.CountryID = A.CountryID
   AND B.StartDate >= A.StartDate 
   AND ISNULL(B.EndDate,'9999-12-31') <= ISNULL(A.EndDate,'9999-12-31')
) 
RAISERROR ('Conflict in date insert',16,1)
ELSE
Insert into ServiceRate(serviceid, startdate, enddate, countryid)
  Select serviceid, startdate, enddate, countryid from inserted
```

Explanation: What I am doing is Checking the data before inserting.
And if the data is in conflict with any Pre-existing data with date then raising an error.

The Else statement takes care in case data is not conflicted.

Hope this will answer your question.

Tried in this [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G7qrrTp7) for you to check

This solution does have a shortcoming and that is if you enter multiple data in which anyone is in conflict then the whole batch will be rejected.

The Solution for the above mentioned problem:

```
Create Trigger CheckDateData ON ServiceRate 
INSTEAD OF Insert
AS
IF EXISTS (
Select Top 1 A.StartDate, A.EndDate, B.StartDate, B.EndDate 
  from ServiceRate A
  INNER JOIN Inserted B ON B.ServiceID = A.ServiceId AND B.CountryID = A.CountryID
   AND B.StartDate >= A.StartDate 
   AND ISNULL(B.EndDate,'9999-12-31') <= ISNULL(A.EndDate,'9999-12-31')
) 
RAISERROR ('Conflict in date insert',16,1)

INSERT INTO ServiceRate(serviceid, startdate, enddate, countryid)
Select b.serviceid, b.startdate, b.enddate, b.countryid
  from ServiceRate A
  RIGHT JOIN Inserted B ON B.ServiceID = A.ServiceId AND B.CountryID = A.CountryID
   AND B.StartDate >= A.StartDate 
   AND ISNULL(B.EndDate,'9999-12-31') <= ISNULL(A.EndDate,'9999-12-31')
  WHERE A.StartDate is null
```

Tried in this [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A5j8FUHE) for you to check

Updating the answer for Update statements.

```
Create Trigger InCheckDateData ON ServiceRate 
INSTEAD OF Insert, Update
AS
IF EXISTS (
Select Top 1 A.StartDate, A.EndDate, B.StartDate, B.EndDate 
  from ServiceRate A
  INNER JOIN Inserted B ON B.ServiceID = A.ServiceId AND B.CountryID = A.CountryID
   AND B.StartDate >= A.StartDate 
   AND ISNULL(B.EndDate,'9999-12-31') <= ISNULL(A.EndDate,'9999-12-31')
) BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Conflict in Dates',16,1)
  END

  ELSE IF EXISTS (Select top 1 1 from Deleted)
BEGIN
  Update s Set s.ServiceID = I.ServiceID, S.StartDate = I.StartDate, S.EndDate = I.EndDate, S.CountryId = I.CountryId
  FROM Servicerate S
  inner join Inserted I on I.ID = S.id
END
ELSE IF not EXISTS (Select top 1 1 from Deleted)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ServiceRate(serviceid, startdate, enddate, countryid)
Select b.serviceid, b.startdate, b.enddate, b.countryid
  from ServiceRate A
  RIGHT JOIN Inserted B ON B.ServiceID = A.ServiceId AND B.CountryID = A.CountryID
   AND B.StartDate >= A.StartDate 
   AND ISNULL(B.EndDate,'9999-12-31') <= ISNULL(A.EndDate,'9999-12-31')
  WHERE A.StartDate is null
END
```

Comment: thanks for this. do you think this type of trigger will work on UPDATE as well?

Comment: Yes but you need to do a little more. Updated my answer and also here. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5cflDhNz).